# unfortunately app has stopped during launching live wall paper

Tags: android

in my there are no compile time errors so i tried to run my code on emulator nut it stopped unfortunately i dont know how to follow the logcat , here i am placing my logcat anyone help me in finding the problem

```
12-14 23:02:20.816: D/dalvikvm(845): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
12-14 23:02:21.516: D/dalvikvm(845): newInstance failed: no <init>()
12-14 23:02:21.556: D/AndroidRuntime(845): Shutting down VM
12-14 23:02:21.556: W/dalvikvm(845): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sri.alinwallpaper/com.sri.alinwallpaper.MyPoint}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.sri.alinwallpaper.MyPoint; no empty constructor
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.sri.alinwallpaper.MyPoint; no empty constructor
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
12-14 23:02:21.666: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  ... 11 more
12-14 23:02:25.496: I/Process(845): Sending signal. PID: 845 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post the MyPoint class code.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you need to provide a constructor that takes no arguments for your `MyPoint` class.

Something like

```
public MyPoint() {
    super();
}
```

Post your whole code so we can confirm that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MyPoint() class object and u don't initializes that object